# Converting a CSR in DER format to PEM format without a private key

Tags: openssl, csr

I have a CSR that I obtained from Okta. Unfortunately, Okta provides the CSR in DER format. I don't have the private key used to generate this CSR, so how would I convert it to PEM format?

Is this possible at all?

Comment: I believe `openssl` tool should help you with that. there are a lot of similar questions on SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use OpenSSL to convert the DER formatted CSR to PEM format.

To do so, here's an example command-line:

```
openssl req -inform DER -outform PEM -in CSR.der -out CSR.pem
```

Comment: @leeharvery1 I get the error - unable to load X509 request when using this command.

Comment: Then I suspect your CSR is either already in PEM format, or not a CSR at all.  Both of which can produce that error.  Try opening your CSR in a text editor, if the first line reads `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----`, then it's already in PEM format.